# Do Quantum Fields have Saturation Limits?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation

Do quantum fields have saturation points. In particular I am wondering about the electromagnetic field, but the question is applicable to all quantum fields. The photon, for example, is an excitation within the EM field. Can a defined area within the field hold endless numbers of photon? Can a defined area within a gravity field hold endless amounts of gravity? To restate my question for clarity here it is: Do quantum fields have capacity limits? Can they ever become full?

Comment: Quantum fields in elementary particles are one field for each particle in the table,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg , a ground state on which a creation  operator can create a particle and and annihilation operator annihilate one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me address several misconceptions in the question:

Quantum fields are *not* what "holds" photons, or other particles. The quantum fields of quantum field theory are the *operators* of the quantum theory, not the *states*. Also, it is difficult to talk about a "defined area" holding particles as localized objects in a relativistic field theory. The proper way to do this would be to consider a QFT on a spacetime with finite spatial extent to begin with, and then ask whether the number operator on the space of states is unbounded above.

Once one forgets about these imprecisions of terminology, the answer is that even in a finite volume of space you can have an arbitraily large amount of particles. The reason is basically that the bosonic [Fock space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space) of asymptotical particle states is *created* to hold arbitrary amounts of particles. For a bosonic field, the reason is simple: Since arbitrarily many bosons can occupy the same state, you can just put more bosons into the lowest-energy non-vacuum state over and over again. For a fermionic field, where you cannot put more than one particle into the same state, you get one possible particle state for every Fourier mode - and even if you've put your theory in a box, you get to arbitrarily high freuqencies as integer multiples of the lowest allowed frequency.